# TYPO3 uid specific navigation

Tags: navigation, typo3, typoscript

I have to edit a typoscript for one uid (and all child uids) of my page.

Let's say I have the following structure:
0

|-1

|-2

| |-20

| |-21

|-3

I want to use the same navigation for uid 1 and 3 but a different one for uid 2,20 and 21.

I have already a Typoscript record using HMENU.

In my typoscript I have a line `SUBNAVI.excludeUidList = 3,754,68`, unfortunately I thought excludeUidList would exclude the navigation for these uids but on uid 3 I still get the menu.

My approach would have been creating a second HMENU object (similar to the

Answer (score 0):

`excludeUidList` excludes these uids from the generated menu.

If you want to generate another menu for these pages (uids) you need to use other mechanism. The easiest way would be TS-conditions, so you also could use `.stdWrap.if`

TS-Condition:
+ fast
- two versions of TS are cached

.stdWrap.if:
+ only one version of TS
- each time both versions are rendered and only one part is shown

```
[PIDinRootline = 2]
// special HMENU for this pagetree
[else]
// HMENU for all other pages
[global]
```

If big parts are identical (your question ends mid sentence) you can write only the differences in the conditions.
But keep in mind: **TS Conditions only on top level, never inside braces of typoscript!**

for example (change a css-class for all menus on pagetree beyond page 2):

```
temp.mainmenu = HMENU
temp.mainmenu {
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        NO = 1
        NO.wrap = <li class="red">|</li>
    }
    2 < .1
}
[PIDinRootline = 2]
temp.mainmenu.1.No.wrap = <li class="blue">|</li>
[global]
```

Comment: Oh well, I didn't see that. crap. Anyway, I think you know what I meant to ask. I want to add a class on uid 2,20 and 21 but not on uid 1 and 3.

You said it's only possible on top level, never inside braces. So I have to make a complete new set of "braces" for my condition to work with only one little additional class?

Comment: That goes into another direction. If you want a special rendering (css) for those pages on every menu, conditions are the wrong approach. Conditions work on the pages **where** the menu is shown. if you want conditions **for** a special range of uids, you can use only `stdWrap.if` with evaluation of the *current* uid (or any other field of these pages)

Comment: maybe you should edit your question to complete the text.

Answer (score -1):

I have solved this adding a new template for adding a class. Additionaly, I added a new css file.